# Clearing a form's textarea and input

Tags: jquery, forms, onclick, textarea

I have a form,

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table>
<tr class="tr_top">
<td class="td_top"><textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="msg" placeholder="Your message here." onfocus='this.select()'><?php
('encode.php');
require ('decode.php');

if (isset($_POST['encode'])) {
echo $encstring;
} elseif (isset($_POST['decode'])) {
echo $decstring;
} ?>
</textarea></td>
</tr>

<tr class="tr_mid">
<td class="td_mid">
<input type=text class="form-control input_mid" name="offset" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['encode']) || isset($_POST['decode'])) { echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['offset']);} ?>" placeholder="Enter a number." pattern="[0-9]{0,3}" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter a number between 1 and 999.')"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr_bottom">
<td class="td_bottom">
<input class="input_bottom btn btn-default" type="submit" name="encode" value="Encode">
<input class="input_bottom btn btn-default" type="submit" name="decode" value="Decode">
<input class="input_bottom btn btn-default" type="button" value="Clear" onclick='this.form.elements.msg.value=""'</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div><!-- close table-responsive -->
</form>
```

where, when clicking the input with the value of "Clear", I want it to clear both the form's textarea and input fields (name="msg" and name="offset", respectively). As it stands, right now this bit of code:

```
value="Clear" onclick='this.form.elements.msg.value=""'
```

only clears the textarea field. How can I get both to clear? I am aware that it's hard-coded to do this, and when I change it to onclick='this.form.elements.offset.value=""' then it works for the input. How do I get it to clear both at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('button').on('click', function() {    
$('.form-control').val('');
});
```

try that, where button is your 'clear' buttons id value.

I think this would work as well

```
$('input[value="Clear"]').on('click', function() {    
$('.form-control').val('');
});
```

Or, if you'd rather opt for an HTML solution:

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

That would clear all input fields in the form

Edit: to load the javascript into your file:

```
...other stuff..
//load jquery if you haven't...
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
//then the code you want to use...
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input[value="Clear"]').on('click', function() {    
    $('.form-control').val('');
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no, in '<script>' tags at the end of your file, before the ending of the body tag

Comment: check out the edit, also this is assuming you've loaded jquery, but anyways I think the input type="reset" would do the trick for you?

Comment: I already had jQuery loaded, so put it at the end and it worked fine. I tried it using input type="reset" but that didn't work, just FYI. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you add the input element with type 'reset' within your form? it doesn't go in javascript

Comment: Yeah, I used it in the html.

Comment: Oh, not sure why it's not working then, I think you're using html5, otherwise that might be why